# "No credentials available" - Credential Manager (Google sign in)

Tags: android, credential-manager, sign-in-with-google

I'm using Credential Manager API in Android, and when I try to sign in with Google on my device, I get a log message **"No credentials available"**. Is there a way to fix this by pointing a user in a right direction to create that google credential, to be able to proceed with Sign in with Google flow? What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your Oauth2 client ID on Google Cloud Console. In my case, I have pasted the wrong SHA1 key.